# Use [(indeterminate)] property in mat-option

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6

I want to use the **[(indeterminate)]** property of **mat-checkbox** in **mat-option**

When I directly used it in **mat-option**, It gave me an error of

**Can't bind to 'indeterminate' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-option'**

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

use it on mat-checkbox

```
<mat-checkbox class="mat-option"   [indeterminate]="itemsSelected "
```

Comment: <mat-select multiple>
  <mat-option [(indeterminate)]="indeterminate">Select All</mat-option>
  <mat-optgroup *ngFor="" >
     <mat-option *ngFor="" [value]="">
                                    {{...}}
     </mat-option>
   </mat-optgroup>
</mat-select>

This is my Sample Code 
And I want to use in mat-option

Answer (score 1):

MatOption does not have an 'indeterminate' property. The concept of an indeterminate state is not applicable to individual selection items in a list - something is either selected or it is not - there is no other possibility.

Checkboxes are not quite the same as list selection items - they can be options or actions, so an indeterminate state does apply, and it indicates that no choice has yet been made. Once a choice has been made, the state can no longer be indeterminate - the checkbox is either on or off.

However, the selection *list* (not the individual selection items) *can* be considered to have an indeterminate state. If the initial state of the list has no selected item, but a selection is required, and the list items can not be unselected except by making a different selection, then the state is indeterminate until the first selection is made. In this pattern, the list is very similar to a radio group without a default selection.

So you can't do what you are trying to do because the property does not exist. Maybe if you shared what exactly you are trying to achieve we might be able to suggest a different approach.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Then, can we use checkbox property in Dropdown?

Comment: Please be more specific about what you are trying to achieve. Create a working Stackblitz example.